# Making use of Metal's volatile MTLPurgeableState while triple buffering

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I have a number of cached `MTLTexture`'s which I would like to set to `purgeable` using `MTLTexture`'s [setPurgeableState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlresource/1515898-setpurgeablestate) API. In order to do this I follow the process outlined in Apple's [2019 WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/606/) which suggests:

- Setting cached `MTLTexture` instances to `volatile`
- Flagging `MTLTexture` instances as `nonVolatile` while 'in use' as part of a command buffer
- Using `MTLCommandBuffer`'s `addCompletedHandler` to set all `MTLTexture` instances back to `volatile` after the command buffer completes its work

This approach works great, but quickly runs into issues in a triple buffered renderer where more than one command buffer is in-flight simultaneously. In these instances I receive the following error:

> Cannot set purgeability state to volatile while resource is in use by a command buffer.

... which makes sense. I'm obviously attempting to flag a `MTLTexture` as `volatile` while it's in-flight as part of a subsequent command buffer. But what's the best way around this without obliterating the performance advantages afforded by triple buffering in the first place?

Attached below is a basic sketch of the approach I'm using (and the one outlined by Apple in the aforementioned WWDC video):

```
let cache = [String:MTLTexture]()

// Insert a number of textures into CPU cache and set
// their purgeable state to volatile
for (key, texture) in cache {
    texture.setPurgeableState(.volatile)
}

// Ensure no more than 3 command buffers are in-flight
// at any given them
semaphore.wait()

// Determine which cached textures are to be used for the
// next render pass and mark them nonVolatile
if cache["texture_to_be_used"].setPurgeableState(.nonVolatile) == .empty {
    // If the texture has been purged recreate as necessary...
}

guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return }

// Construct command buffer, binding textures where necessary
// ...

// Set a completion handler for the command buffer
commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler({ (buffer) in
    // Set any textures marked as nonVoltile back to volatile
    // so that they can be purged when required
    //
    // The issue here is that as I'm using a triple buffered
    // approach I have no way of (efficiently) knowing if a given
    // texture is being bound as part of another in-flight
    // command buffer
    for (key, texture) in cache {
        texture.setPurgeableState(.volatile)
    }

    // Rely on a semaphore to manage triple buffered rendering
    self.semaphore.signal()
})
commandBuffer.commit()
```

Comment: If they are being used every time, there's no point in making them purgeable. You'd just be playing a game of "memory pressure got too high, to my resource got evicted, but now I need to recreate it". Otherwise, you'd have to use completion handlers on a command buffer.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood. The resources aren't being used "every time". They regularly go unused, which is why I'm marking them as volatile, and I *am* using completion handlers. The issue is that a subsequent in-flight command buffer may still hold a reference to the texture as it's being marked as volatile. This, according to Apple, is best practice. Mark the textures as nonVolatile when they are needed for a render pass, and then reset their state to volatile after that pass. The issue is that I have multiple in-flight command buffers and need to determine how to safely do this.

Comment: @ndg please provide some example code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I can suggest working around the error by first querying if the texture is already `nonVolatile` by passing `keepCurrent` to `setPurgeableState`. If that doesn't work, then there's a bug in metal validation layer, and you would probably need to file a feedback request.

Comment: Also, of course, as with any problem in software, you can add another level of abstraction to check for this case, but that highly depends on the architecture of your app.

Comment: @HamidYusifli I've attached some pseudo code to explain the approach as laid out by Apple. 

JustSomeGuy: I'm not sure how this would help? The issue is that as one command buffer completes its work and attempts to set the cached textures back to volatile another command buffer is in-flight (which subsequently makes use of the same texture). Essentially I need a way to guarantee that none of my in-flight command buffers (out of the 3 I'm using in my triple buffered approach) are utilising a given texture before I set it's volatile state. I'm at a loss as to how to do that efficiently.

Comment: I see. You'd probably then have to track this in some separate map, that's going to count the command buffer "references" to those textures and put them back to volatile when they aren't referenced anymore. I don't think there's an easy way to do that otherwise, because the API doesn't have any machinery to report to you if the resource is in use by an in-flight command buffer or not.